# How user authorization settings apply to Replication Sets in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

**###Environment : MongoDB 3.4**

I want to set my replication sets on my Linux machine.

**--First**, I just install `MongoDB`, and edit the configuration of `mongod` from `/etc/mongod.conf` to turn on authorization by adding

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

to the file.

And then I create my account to the database `admin`:

```
db.createUser(  
{ 
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "admin",  
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]  
}
)
```

**--Then** I add my replication config to the `/etc/mongod.conf` again by adding

```
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

Then I restart `mongod` using `$ service mongod restart`

And I launch `mongo`   (Everything goes fine here. )

(In mongo)

`>use admin`

`>db.auth("admin", "admin")`

`1`

**It seems that I pass the authorization here.** But when I try to get rs's status through `>rs.status()`

Problem comes:

```
> rs.status()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { 
replSetGetStatus: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

I do not know what happened. Is the authorization just apply to `admin`? But my user role is `userAdminAnyDatabase`.